# Small image id auto added when adding journal article in liferay?

Tags: liferay-6

I used the following code to add a journal article (liferay 6.1):

```
JournalArticle ja = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle(
userId, groupId, 0, 0, StringPool.BLANK, true,
JournalArticleConstants.VERSION_DEFAULT, titleMap, descriptionMap,
content, "general", structureId, templateId, StringPool.BLANK,
1, 1, 2008, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true,
true, false, StringPool.BLANK, null, null, StringPool.BLANK,
serviceContext);
```

For simplicity, I omitted some parts of the code. As specified in the parameters, smallImage = false. However, when adding new journal article, in the journalarticle table, the column SmallImageId always added a number which I was expecting as 0. Does anyone have experience on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reaseon eludes me, but this behaviour is as expected (as programmed) because of this part of JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle method

```
article.setSmallImage(smallImage);
article.setSmallImageId(counterLocalService.increment());
article.setSmallImageURL(smallImageURL);
```

only later in method is

```
saveImages(smallImage, article.getSmallImageId(), smallImageFile, smallImageBytes);
```

which is only part that checks smallImage boolean parameter

```
protected void saveImages(
        boolean smallImage, long smallImageId, File smallImageFile,
        byte[] smallImageBytes)
    throws PortalException, SystemException {

    if (smallImage) {
        if ((smallImageFile != null) && (smallImageBytes != null)) {
            imageLocalService.updateImage(smallImageId, smallImageBytes);
        }
    }
    else {
        imageLocalService.deleteImage(smallImageId);
    }
}
```

Funny part is that workflow for new article **without** small image is as follows (only relevant parts):

1. create new article
2. save image (which you do not want) which actualy tries to remove image that you do not have